# Passing an array of html inputs as a parameter to an Oracle procedure

Tags: html, forms, post, plsql

I need to send this array of inputs into an Oracle procedure, which I don't know their names in advance (NAME = ID in DB).

```
<FORM ACTION="TESTPKG.FORMSAVE" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="1" VALUE="54642">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="2" VALUE="4141">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="5" VALUE="541671">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="6" VALUE="41542">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="7" VALUE="546424">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="9" VALUE="7815174">
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Save">
</FORM>
```

How the input parameter should look like in the procedure FORMSAVE? If it could be done just using some TYPE, it would be great.

So I can easily use it e.g. like this:

```
FOR i IN 1..inputs.count LOOP
    something??
END LOOP;
```

I'm using Oracle 11.2 as my database.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What kind of processing can you have outside the procedure? That is, do you need to pass the parameter as a single text value, and in this case I'd suggest a CLOB, or can you elaborate this value to build some more structured type?

Comment: I don't need to pass it as a single text value. I have free hands here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it using Flexible parameter passing (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12303/concept.htm#1005765)

My procedure FORMSAVE now looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE FORMSAVE(name_array in owa.vc_arr, value_array in owa.vc_arr) IS
BEGIN
    FOR n IN 1..name_array.count
    LOOP
        htp.print(name_array (n) || ': ' || value_array(n)); -- example
    END LOOP;
END FORMSAVE;
```

Plus, action attribute in the form syntax must contain exclamation mark:

```
<FORM ACTION="!TESTPKG.FORMSAVE" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a type to handle your data; for example:

```
create or replace type tyRecord as object (
                                           type   varchar2(10),
                                           name   varchar2(10),
                                           value  number(10)
                                           );
create or replace type tyList as table of tyRecord;
```

Your procedure could be something like this:

```
create or replace procedure testInput(pInput IN tyList) is
begin
    for i in pInput.first .. pInput.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line( pInput(i).type || ' - ' ||
                              pInput(i).name || ' - ' ||  
                              pInput(i).value
                            );  
    end loop;
end;
```

The call:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vList tyList := tyList();
  3  begin
  4      for i in 1 .. 3 loop
  5          vList.extend();
  6          vList(vList.last) := tyRecord('INPUT', i, i * 100);
  7      end loop;
  8      --
  9      testInput(vList);
 10  end;
 11  /
INPUT - 1 - 100
INPUT - 2 - 200
INPUT - 3 - 300

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: How can I send this list of objects after form submit? This form is also made in PLSQL procedure. It would be best to parse output sent directly from form.

Comment: This brings us back to my previous question How can you pass the values? If you can do whatever you want in the caller, you should be able to parse the data and fill a structure like the one in my example. If you have some more limitations, maybe it would be better to pass the value as a single CLOB and parse it from within the procedure